# Why does this where query no longer work properly for ShopifyAPI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, ruby-on-rails-6, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to do a simple `where` query on both the `Checkout` class and `Order` class via the REST ShopifyAPI, but it keeps returning inaccurate data.

Here are two examples:

```
[12] pry(main)> Order.count
=> 9
[13] pry(main)> Order.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.minute)..(Time.now)).count
=> 9
[14] pry(main)> Order.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.second)..(Time.now)).count
=> 9
[15] pry(main)> Order.first.created_at
=> "2021-05-15T02:59:36-05:00"
[16] pry(main)> Order.last.created_at
=> "2021-04-23T02:43:44-05:00"
```

And the same thing for `Checkout`:

```
[8] pry(main)> Checkout.where(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..(Time.now)).count
=> 6
[9] pry(main)> Checkout.where(created_at: (Time.now - 10.minutes)..(Time.now)).count
=> 6
[10] pry(main)> Checkout.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.minute)..(Time.now)).count
=> 6
[11] pry(main)> Checkout.count
=> 6
[18] pry(main)> Checkout.first.created_at
=> "2021-04-29T00:13:16-05:00"
[19] pry(main)> Checkout.last.created_at
=> "2021-05-15T03:00:37-05:00"
```

What could be the cause of this?

**Edit 1**

Strangely enough, this issue seems to not show itself when I try another model like `Product`:

```
[28] pry(main)> Product.where(title: "High Coverage Foundation").count
=> 1
[29] pry(main)> Product.count
=> 6
```

That's the correct feedback I was expecting. I am expecting something similar for the `Order` model too, but for some reason it isn't working properly.

I have restarted my local terminal session, and reinstalled my Shopify-api-cli...to no avail.

**Edit 2**

See more examples from both classes that show the existence of those objects which indicates that the query should work.

```
[51] pry(main)> Order.first.id
=> 3779683877046
[52] pry(main)> Order.last.id
=> 3741986750646
[53] pry(main)> Order.first.created_at
=> "2021-05-15T02:59:36-05:00"
[54] pry(main)> Order.last.created_at
=> "2021-04-23T02:43:44-05:00"
[55] pry(main)> Checkout.first.id
=> "ef8dd57a1b1911da9077df7789698847"
[56] pry(main)> Checkout.last.id
=> "7133c7aeb0ff3b4b506c2a66e4190ee3"
[57] pry(main)> Checkout.first.created_at
=> "2021-04-29T00:13:16-05:00"
[58] pry(main)> Checkout.last.created_at
=> "2021-05-15T03:00:37-05:00"
```

**Edit 3**

So it seems that it works for queries done on attributes that have a `string`, but not an `integer` and `datetime` is inconsistent:

```
[79] pry(main)> Order.where(cart_token: '36e017f94cbf19bee298d61334b68225').count
=> 1 // #RIGHT
[80] pry(main)> Order.where(created_at: '2021-05-15T02:59:36-05:00').count
=> 9 // #WRONG
[81] pry(main)> Order.where(current_total_price: 294.14).count
=> 9 // #WRONG
[82] pry(main)> Order.where(email: 'alex@test.com').count
=> 1 // #RIGHT
[83] pry(main)> Order.where(processed_at: '2021-05-15T02:59:35-05:00').count
=> 3 // #RIGHT STRANGELY ENOUGH
[97] pry(main)> Order.where(processed_at: '2021-05-15T02:59:35-05:00').first.id
=> 3779683877046 // #RIGHT
[98] pry(main)> Order.where(processed_at: '2021-05-15T02:59:35-05:00').last.id
=> 3779668639926 // #RIGHT
```

Comment: Are you sure their API supports time ranges like that? Are you using a gem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing `Checkout.where(created_at: (Time.now - 1.minute)..(Time.now)).first` and/or `last` instead of `Checkout.first/last`?

Comment: @Joel_Blum their API supports ActiveResource, so I assume that it does. Btw, when I do a `where` for a singular resource (e.g. an exact ID) it returns the same `9` on the count, so I know it is broken regardless.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I was just using `Checkout.first` and `Checkout.last` to show you timestamps to indicate that there shouldn't be 9 objects returned in the original `where` query due to the `created_at` timestamps of those records. That's all that was.

Comment: Would be helpful to see the actual http request that got made. Also looking at the docs should it be preceded with ShopifyAPI and use find instead of where?

Comment: @Joel_Blum not sure how to see the actual HTTP request being made, because I am doing this via their console script via terminal. I auto included `ShopifyAPI` with all calls at the top of my console session. When I tried to use `find` instead of `where`, this is what happens...see next comment.

Comment: @Joel_Blum `[25] pry(main)> Order.find(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..(Time.now)).count
E, [2021-05-16T03:37:54.930918 #82915] ERROR -- : GET https://myapp.myshopify.com:443/admin/api/2021-04/orders/%7B%3Acreated_at%3D%3E2021-05-15+03%3A37%3A54.407852+-0500..2021-05-16+03%3A37%3A54.422452+-0500%7D.json
E, [2021-05-16T03:37:54.931009 #82915] ERROR -- : --> 404 Not Found 22 (477.2ms)
ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found (Not Found).
from /activeresource-5.1.1/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:147:in 'handle_response'`

Comment: That HTTP request only shows up when an error is generated. @Joel_Blum

Comment: I checked the list of methods available on the `Order` object, and I see `where` available, so it should work. It used to work and I have seen some examples of other apps of similar queries working. For example - https://khawa.tech/posts/develop-shopify-application-ruby-rails/

Comment: I added some more feedback from my troubleshooting. See the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response on Shopify's official [forum which can be seen here](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Why-does-this-where-query-no-longer-work-properly-for-REST/td-p/1172851).

TL;DR, Shopify's rubygem doesn't implement ranged dates exactly like ActiveRecord does, they use `created_at_min` and `created_at_max` attributes on the model.

So the correct query for the `ShopifyAPI` for that where query is:

```
ShopifyAPI::Order.where(created_at_min: Time.now - 6.days, created_at_max: Time.now).count
```